# mysql min ignores null - need workaround/tweak

Tags: mysql

For this query

```
SELECT min(date) min_date FROM  order_products group by order_id
```

`min_date` ignores the `NULL` values in a group of order id.

In my case I want min_date = NULL if the group has a order_products tuple with null value in date.

Any idea how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple workAround could be:

```
SELECT min(IFNULL(date, '1970-01-01')) AS min_date 
FROM order_products 
GROUP BY order_id
```

So, if 1970/01/01 turns up, you know that there's a NULL value.

Comment: this query returns all the min_date values as '1970-01-01'. Are u sure this one works, have u tried it before ?

Comment: @shikhar: No, I didn't try it before, but I tried it now and it's working for me. Maybe there are NULLs in all orders?

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when count(date)=sum(1) then min(date) else null end
```

or, when all rows are not null, return min date, else return null.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of doing that, if your problem domain allows defining a "absolute minimum date", is to use ISNULL()/COALESCE() expression to turn a nullable field into non-null.

`ISNULL(dateField, '1000-01-01')`

Another (f no meaningful "smallest" default can be defined) is to do it via 2 queries - first select stuff WITH nulls, then if the result set is empty, add in stuff where date is not null

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about finding the minimum date from multiple columns, then the following could help;

```
SELECT 
      LEAST
            (IFNULL(date_1, date(CURRENT_DATE()+1)),
            IFNULL(date_2, date(CURRENT_DATE()+1)),
            IFNULL(date_3, date(CURRENT_DATE()+1))) as MinimumDate
FROM YourTable;
```